# Smartfox example (tris) for dynamic rooms is not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, smartfoxserver

I'm having a problem running the tris example of smartfox server. The [site](http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/ExamplesUnity/tris)
has the installation instruction. The game creates a dynamic rooms however when I check the zone monitor module and monitors the newly created room, the room extension tab is disabled. The log also display a SFSextension exception.

> com.smartfoxserver.v2.exceptions.SFSExtensionException: No extensions
> can be invoked: { Zone: BasicExamples }

Does the example a creates new room extension?

> settings.Extension = new RoomExtension(extensionId, extensionClass);
>
> //Taken from the site

Why did extensions can't be invoked?
Or did I just miss a thing?

---

Other notes:

> x64 Windows
>
> Java 1.8_25 (both jdk and jre)
>
> Server version: 2.9.0
>
> Google Chrome version: 39.0.2171.99 m

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the smartfox server 2x documentation on tris. The document says

> copy the tris folder from the /deploy/extensions folder to your SFS2X
>   installation folder, under /SFS2X/extensions;

The problem is that I created a folder under the /SFS2X/extensions different from the /deploy/extensions folder.

Note that in the LobbyGUI.cs, extensionId name must be equal to the folder name in the extension manager folder.

```
private const string extensionId = "tris";
```

[image]